# How to create an anonymous Google account using TorBrowser

Tags: google, verification

I want to create an anonymous Google account using Tor and a free SMS receiving service. However, when I use Tor, I can't get phone number verification. What should I do?

Comment: The words "anonymous" and "google" (as in the queen of data mining whooors) seem a bit oxymoronic. One might as well ask why Tor would align itself with Stackexchange since Stack is sell you out to google via Captcha and email for signup demands. Makes no sense to me but I'm sure google apologists will claim it's to weed out the "bad guys" - when many who use Tor use it simply for...(wait for it)... some semblance of ANONIMITY. Same with the other sign up options Stack's offering, i.e., two other major data mining whooors... Yahoo and Facebook. SMH